# Pass a operator = to a function object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, bind

I try to pass a  bind an operator () with a function object. Then I would like to use this function object as a custom comparator in a map that I declare. But I get the following compile error

> error C3867: 'Comparator::operator ()': non-standard syntax; use '&'
>   to create a pointer to member
>   1>
>   error C2672: 'std::bind': no matching overloaded function found
>
> error C2923: 'std::map': 'predict' is not a valid template type
>   argument for parameter '_Pr'

I do not want to use lamda expressions

The code that I have written is the following

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
struct Comparator : std::binary_function<int const &, int const &, bool>
{
    template<typename T>
    bool operator()(T const & a, T const & b)
    {
        return a < b;
    }
};
int main()
{

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    std::function<bool(Comparator&,int const &, int const &)> predict = 
    std::bind(Comparator::operator(), std::placeholders::_1, 
     std::placeholders::_2);
    std::map<int, int, predict> x;

}
```

Comment: Why do you need a templatized `operator()`?

Comment: why dont you want to use lambdas? You can always write a lamda as functor class, for more boilerplate and (almost) nothing in return

Comment: It clearly tells you that you need to use `&Comparator::operator()` as the first parameter to `std::bind`.

Comment: Why not just use `std::map<int, int, Comparator>`?  What's the point of the `bind` here?

Comment: FWIW, there is [`std::less<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void) which does just this.

Comment: Notice that `std::binary_function` has been removed since C++17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `std::bind` or a lambda here.  `Comparator` is a perfectly valid comparator, so you can just declare `x` as:

```
std::map<int, int, Comparator> x;
```

If your actual `Comparator` has some state that you need to initialize, you can pass a `Comparator` object to `std::map`'s constructor:

```
Comparator cmp{some, constructor, args};
std::map<int, int, Comparator> x{cmp};
```

Answer (score 2):

After binding you get functor which takes 2 params (int,int), signature of function `std::function<bool(Comparator&,int const &, int const &)>` is wrong - `Comparator` is redundant, try this:

```
    std::function<bool(int const &, int const &)> predict = 
       std::bind( Comparator(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

     std::map<int, int, decltype(predict)> x{predict};
```

Comment: You can directly initialize `predict` with `Comparator()`, and actually you don't need `predict` at all.

Comment: Does `std::bind` keep the ownership of temporary object `Comparator()` passed as the first argument?

Comment: @BiagioFesta It stores its copy.

Comment: @BiagioFesta Yes, all parameters to `std::bind` are copied into the bind object.

Comment: Is any alternative without use decltype. I would like to port this code in C++98 compiler using boost

Comment: How? there is no `std::bind` in Cpp98.

Comment: I will use the boost::bind and boost::function

Comment: @getsoubl To be frank, I don't know if it is possible to work under C++98. But you don't need to use `bind` here at all, as was mentioned in comments you can just pass `Comparator` as 3rd param of `map` , and should work.